# (could not convert string to float) error while using knn algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yO3Z.png)

So I am trying to implement KNN classification algorithm but am facing an error while trying to fit the model. Please help guys I am a beginner.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9qf5.png)

[Data type of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CA5nS.png)

The numeric columns which are of object type are the ones giving the error cause when I try to fit without them then its working. How to convert them

Comment: To use the KNN algorithm, model assumes that ever feature is numeric and if any feature is non-numeric it will thrown an error.

Comment: make ure you converted categories into one-hot encoding and if it is string convert it into vectorization such as bag of words or TF-IDF.

Comment: ok i converted the land use column into numeric values still I am getting the same error

Comment: are you getting the same error? or any different error ?

Comment: I am getting the exact same error. When I tried to fit it by excluding some columns using hit and trial it is working.But I want it to work for all the columns.

Comment: I have edited and added to the question, please check above. Thanks

Comment: @giri Object meaning that it contains the string and you have to convert them into the numeric form by changing its datatype to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have any non-numerique features on your dataset. You should use encoding for all of your non-numerique features.
[Scikit Learn Preprocessing](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing)

Comment: I converted it all into numeric values still I am getting the same error

Comment: Please edit your question with a print of the head of the dataframe given with the full traceback. The first traceback was linked to the encoding for sure.

Comment: I have edited the question now, can you please check.